# Unable to load a .pem from a resource file on macOS

Tags: c#, .net-core, ssl-certificate

I have a simple method that loads a pem certificate from a resource file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to load a .pem and return it as a X509Certificate2
    /// </summary>
    private static X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate2(string path)
    {
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(path))
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            return new X509Certificate2(data);
        }
    }
```

It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu, but fails on macOS with the following:

> Interop+AppleCrypto+AppleCommonCryptoCryptographicException : Unknown
>   format in import.

I tried using the `Span<byte>` overload, but to little avail.

Does anyone have any ideas/work-arounds?

Thanks

Comment: Is there perhaps leading or trailing extra data?  Can you share a value that isn't working?

Comment: I'm not sure - I'm using this certificate (the first expired one I could find for testing): https://www.sk.ee/upload/files/Juur-SK.pem.crt

Comment: Yeah, but are you possibly getting weird bytes prepended or appended by your resource creation process.  Have you looked at the actual bytes in `data`? Also, your read isn't guaranteed to read everything / fill `data`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, so I don't expect any exotic transforms are affecting the resource.  It's possible that the Read isn't reading to the end, but it's suspicious that this would work on Windows and Ubuntu...

Comment: I can rule out the Read (the number of bytes read matches the stream length) and the byte array seems to be populated OK... any other ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a ticket with the corefx team here (which I have now closed): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35163

The exception was caused by the file actually containing a chain of certificates (it contained multiple `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` markers) - the underlying Interop doesn't support this on macOS.

Apparently, Windows only uses the first one it comes across as well, so the solution was just to read enough bytes from the stream until that marker is hit (although there's no reason why the entire chain couldn't be extracted as a collection of `X509Certificate2`).

Oddly, the file I had in my assembly (which contained a certificate chain) is different to the file I linked to above...  My thanks and apologies to @bartonjs as this wouldn't have helped!